# Why is my IP adress different when displayed by different methods

Tags: ip, wifi

I am new to all this, so I am sorry if the question is stupid. I am learning about networking and I want to find out IP address of my own computer.

When I try to display it through **ipconfig**, **my router's configuration page** and **by simply googling**, I see different IP-address

Thank you in advance for help

in ip-config it starts with *10. ...*
in router's conf page *192.168.1. ...*
when googling *213. ...*

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it has nothing to do with programming. Your computer's wireless NIC has its own IP, your router has *multiple* IPs, and your public connection has yet another IP. What you are seeing is due to standard NATing: network address translation that is very commonly used. You need to do research on your own about basic networking and NAT.

Comment: This should probably be moved over to SuperUsers.

Answer (score 1):

`ipconfig` will give you the address of your machine. This will be some *private IP address*. Your router will have two IP address - One *public* and one *private*. All machines in your local network (house probably) will talk to the router via its private address, while everything out in the Internet talk to your router via its public address.

So, `ipconfig` provides the address of your computer, your router's config page shows its private address, and Google will show you your router's public address.

Some terms to look up: Look up Public vs Private IP addresses and how NAT works and this will all make more sense.

Comment: Just some pedantry - in this user's case, both interfaces of the router are privately (ie, RFC 1918) addressed, with the upstream interface (on a `192.168.1/24` network) connected to the cable/DSL/whatever modem provided by the ISP, which *itself* is publicly addressed.

Comment: @admdrew, good point. I hadn't thought about that. I don't know much about the operation of consumer ISPs :)

Comment: @user3284632, feel free to mark this as correct if it is satisfactory